# Finding conditions(boolean) from required behavior of variables

Tags: statistics, boolean

I have a really nice case now.
I have a function depending on 2 variables, and I need to implement the code of this function to respond correctly as given expectations table

```
const cases = [
            [1, 1, false],
            [1, 2, true],
            [1, 3, false],
            [1, 4, true],
            [1, 5, false],
            [1, 6, true],
            [2, 1, true],
            [2, 2, false],
            [2, 3, true],
            [2, 4, false],
            [2, 5, true],
            [2, 6, false],
        ];


// not relevant but fyi as code is js used jest testeach to check all of cases outputs
test.each(
            cases,
            function(nr1, nr2, expected) {
                expect(isInGroup(nr1, nr2)).toBe(expected);
            },
        );
```

Above are the cases in format [firstNr: int, secondNr: int, expectedFunctionOutput: bool]

function signature is as below

```
export function isInGroup(firstNr, secondNr) {
    // TODO implement
    // return correct stuff
}
```

PS: Distribution of cases is such that makes sure both variable1, and variable2 have 50% `true` cases out of total cases where they are present.

I tried initially something like distributing them in groups without success, got 75% of test cases covered only from provided test cases.

```
export function isInGroup(firstNr, secondNr) {
    return (
        (firstNr % 2 === 0 && secondNr % 2 === 0) ||
        (firstNr % 2 !== 0 && secondNr % 2 === 0) ||
        (firstNr % 2 === 0 && secondNr % 2 !== 0)
    );
}
```

Also as values are numbers not bools cannot use boolean tables directly find the formulae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.

This function gives desired result:

```
return firstNr % 2 !== 0 ? secondNr % 2 === 0 : secondNr % 2 !== 0;
```